# How to filter query in sqlalchemy by year (datetime column)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have table in sqlalchemy 0.4 that with types.DateTime column:

```
Column("dfield", types.DateTime, index=True)
```

I want to select records, that has specific year in this column, using model. How to do this?
I though it should be done like this:

```
selected_year = 2009
my_session = model.Session()
my_query = my_session.query(model.MyRecord).filter(model.dfield.??? == selected_year)

# process data in my_query
```

Part with ??? is for me unclear.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
sqlalchemy.extract('year', model.MyRecord.dfield) == selected_year
```

For referene: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.extract

Comment: Thanks! I never saw the `extract` before. Works as expected.