# search by year/month using flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

everbody,

About search by year/month using flask-sqlalchemy..

Is there any pythonic and short way to search by year/month ?

```
myquery = Table.query.filter(Table.dt.year == 2016, Table.dt.month == 10)
```

*(this is actually incorrect, but only to express my logic)*

Where Table and dt are something like that:

```
class Table(db.Model):

    ...
    dt = db.Column(db.Datetime)
```

Comment: Yes, It is very similar. I found my solution based on this link, thank you for help. I found two ways to do this.I put this solution below.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution I tested is use on filter instead filter(...).filter(...)

Example:

```
.filter(extract('year', Record.dt) == 2016, extract('month', Record.dt) == 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453591/how-to-filter-query-in-sqlalchemy-by-year-datetime-column) and [link](https://www.facebook.com/groups/FlaskFrameworkCommunity/)

Simply do:

```
.filter(extract('year', Table.dt) == 2016).filter(extract('month', Table.dt) == 10).all()
```

And extract is from *sqlalchemy*, so it is necessary import this:

```
from sqlalchemy import extract
```