# Sqlite Flask SQLalchemy count how many items per month

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a flask python app and a sqlite table, using sqlalchemy.

When the user hits submit button on a form in the app a datetime now value is created in python and is then passed to the "createdate" column in the sqlite database and has form "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".  The column was setup in the model as a Text string so I assume its a string when it goes to the model.

I want to create a chartjs graph that shows each month on the x-axis and number of "createdates" for each month on the y-axis.

I am using flask-login so only the data owned by current user should be included.  This is all I have so far:

THis is my model:

```
class Customer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer)
    gigtype = db.Column(db.Integer)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(100))
    gigdate = db.Column(db.Text)
    info = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    cost = db.Column(db.Integer)
    paid = db.Column(db.Integer)
    createdate = db.Column(db.Text)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

This is my main.py route so far, I'm completely lost on how I do this.  I don't know if this can be done directly with sqlalchemy or if I need to loop through the "createdate" column.  I don't know if even using datetime is the best solution or if I should just strip the text string and find the ones with 04 (april), for example.  I would prefer to leave my sqlite database as-is and work with what I have.  My end goal is to have a total count for each month and bring it into chartjs via jinja:

```
@main.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
def dashboard():

    all_data = Customer.query.filter_by(owner_id=current_user.name)

    return render_template('dashboard.html', name=current_user.name, customers=all_data)
```

Comment: Since you are using SQLalchemy you could use the [grouping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html?highlight=group#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.group_by) functions to produce an aggregated view of your data. In clear use groupby. Then to render a chart on the screen I think it's going be easier to use Javascript. With render_template you could pass a json structure containing the data and let the chart library deal with that data. An example is [chartjs](
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/).

Comment: I should have told you I'm a beginner. I am just trialing and erroring with sqlalchemy and reading the error logs as I go.  So far I have this but its giving me an error but I'm guessing I need to convert the 'createdate' values to a month value inside of the query: timedata = Customer.query.filter_by(owner_id=current_user.name).group_by(Customer.createdate.strftime("%m")).all()

Answer (score 0):

I found a working partial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043051/search-by-year-month-using-flask-sqlalchemy)

I can do a line like this for each month, or create a list of 12 items to represent # per month:

```
april_data = Customer.query.filter_by(owner_id=current_user.name).filter(extract('year', Customer.createdate) == 2021).filter(extract('month', Customer.createdate) == 4).count()
```

Comment: Now I need a pythonic way to loop through the query for each month and come up with a list, any ideas?