# keyword can't be an expression - filtering in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I create simple database with sqlalchemy

```
class BlogPost(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    post = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    create_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
```

create_date is in format (year-month-day h:m:s.ms):

```
2018-02-20 21:45:37.591733
```

I used datetime.datetime

I'd like to filter for example all posts with year=2018 and here i got problem:

```
posts = BlogPost.query.filter_by(create_date.year=2018)
```

it is possible to use datetime.year but i can't use it as an expression in sqlalchemy filtering, above code returns:

```
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Correct syntax would be: `create_date=...`, but i need to compare only year, not whole data object

Is it possible to do that in a simple way? Any suggestions?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128505/whats-the-difference-between-filter-and-filter-by-in-sqlalchemy and any of the other questions and answers that come up, if you search with that error message for why you're getting that. The actual answer to your problem depends a bit on your DB in use, but probably you need the SQL function EXTRACT, or some other method.

Comment: oh I couldn't find that! Thank you very much!

Comment: Related: [How to filter query in sqlalchemy by year (datetime column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453591/how-to-filter-query-in-sqlalchemy-by-year-datetime-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach would be to use either `between()`:

```
from datetime import datetime
dt_from = datetime(2018, 1, 1)
dt_to = datetime(2018, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59)

BlogPost.query.filter(db.between(BlogPost.create_date, dt_from, dt_to))
```

or `and_()` notation:

```
BlogPost.query.filter(db.and_(BlogPost.create_date >= dt_from, BlogPost.create_date <= dt_to))
```

#### Further info in the docs:

- [sqlalchemy.sql.expression.between](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.between)
- [sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_)

Comment: If you make that a half open range, you can handle those pesky milliseconds at the end of the year too.

Comment: yes, agreed! between is inclusive so the and_ construct may better serve your use case here

Comment: I a little modified this solution but still helps me a lot, thank you both! :)